# Git diff returns “Error: Process completed with exit code 1.” Github Actions

Tags: git, diff, github-actions, git-diff

The following command git diff --no-index --output=restapi-diff.txt latest-restapi.json restapi.json returns exit code 1 without any further details. When using actions checkout.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there was/is no problem. Figured out, linux `diff` (similar to gits diff check) and gits `git diff` returns `1` if there are changes or differences between files and 0 otherwise.

So `exit status 1` does not necessarily indicate a fail when using `diff` (linux) or `git diff` from git.

The right thing to do is `continue-on-error` when using github actions or ignore this status in other build systems.